# python dynamic webscraping javascript content

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Python and Selenium to scrape a website. What I do is go to the [homepage](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/united-states.html), type in a keyword, such as 1300746-79-5. On the [resulting page](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search?interface=CAS%20No.&term=1300746-79-5&N=0&mode=match%20partialmax&focus=product&lang=en&region=US), I am trying to scrape the data in the "pricing" section. Specifically, I need to get the "SKU-Pack Size" and "Price(USD)" information. But these information is Javascript encripted, so I cannot see them in the source code. I am wondering how I can achieve this.

I have written some code that gets me to the page of interest, but I still cannot see the javascript information. Here is what I have so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pprint

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Rei\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/united-states.html")

print driver.title
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Query")

# type in the search
inputElement.send_keys("1300746-79-5")
inputElement.submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have done looks correct to me.

"SKU-Pack Size" and "Price(USD)" information are not "encrypted", but retrieved after JavaScript clicking action. All you need to do is to click product name or pricing link.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pprint

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/united-states.html")

print driver.title
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Query")

# type in the search
inputElement.send_keys("1300746-79-5")
inputElement.submit()

pricing_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.priceValue a")
print pricing_link.text
pricing_link.click()

# then deal with the data you want
price_table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".priceAvailContainer tbody"))
)
print 'price_table.text: ' + price_table.text

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you explain what I should do after doing the javascript clicking action? I still do not see the SKU and pricing information in the source code...I am thinking of using beautifulsoup to extract the specific elements. But my code does not return the product url, so I am clueless.

Comment: @user3788728: Hmm. Sounds like something is wrong. Can you see it in the UI (with your eyes)? What are your Selenium, Chrome, ChromeDriver versions?

Comment: my chrome version is 35.0.1916.153 , ChromeDriver is 2.9. I downloaded selenium this morning, so it should be the most recent version.

Comment: I can see it if I highlight the section and select view element. But if I just go into page source, they are not shown

Comment: @user3788728: Everything works fine here. I will post complete code above. I'm not experiencing any issues getting the data. Page source might have some limitations regarding AJAX calls. Any particular reasons you care about page source in the first place?

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I'm fairly new to web scraping (and Python in general) so all I learned was using bs4 to scrape structured html content. that's why I hope to see the information in page source.